# Glottal stop "t" in English pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

I am a new learner concerning English sounds. Could someone help me?

Does the letter *t* at the end of word but this word being connected with next one, is it also pronounced like a glottal stop? For example, that it was ......, the last "t" in *that*.

Comment: If you're a new learner, it might be better not to worry about this kind of detail that will not keep you from being understood, but on more basic aspects of the English language.

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes pronounced this way, but not in any of the *official* English you're likely to be taught. (American English or British Received Pronunciation - RP.)

For example, estuary English spoken in the London area, as well as some Scottish and American pronunciations, can have this feature.

But I would not recommend imitating it unless you are communicating primarily with people who pronounce it this way.